# Adding an array list to a session

Tags: java, struts2

Im trying to store an array list in session like so:

```
private Map session = ActionContext.getContext().getSession();
```

The array list looks like this:

```
private ArrayList<Integer> numbersEntered = new ArrayList<Integer>();
```

If the array list doesn't already exist in session it is added but Im having problems adding new data to the array list and updating the session with that data. So - my problem is how do I get what is already in session, store it temporarily, add to it based on the user input and re-add to the session?

```
if ( !session.containsKey(arrayListID) ) 
{
// Place the number the user entered into the session
session.put(arrayListID, numbersEntered);
} else {

// Retrieve session data
 }
```

I retrieve what was stored initially and placed it in a string but because it was anm array list it was stored like: [12]. I don't want to have to convert it or split the string...Let me know if you need more info here.

Cheers

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
if ( !session.containsKey(arrayListID) ) 
{
// Place the number the user entered into the session
session.put(arrayListID, numbersEntered);
} else {
    ArrayList<Integer> list = (ArrayList<Integer>) session.get(arrayListID);
     list.add( 1 /* what you want */);
// Retrieve session data
 }
```

Comment: .getAttribute() is undefined for maps

Comment: I'm sorry i think you were using HttpSession

Comment: ArrayList<Integer> list = (ArrayList<Integer>) session.get(arrayListID);

Comment: this works but can you clarify something for me? This is casting from an object(the values) to an array list. This array list is basically inheriting the values in the first array list. But when does this get placed back in session? Is the arraylist list just acting as a pointer to the same value in the map?\

Comment: The Map Object returned by ActionContext.getContext().getSession() use the arrayListID value to retieve the list, if you want to ovverride the list you have to remove it from the map (session.remove(arrayListID)) or invoking session.put(arrayListID, new List) to replace it;

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/21020/discussion-between-giordano-maestro-and-katana24)